# How could I get my program to cycle through a list of wav files?

Tags: java, audio, wav

I've finally integrated a soundtrack into this game I'm making, but it's only one song long. How could I get this to cycle through some songs to expand my soundtrack?

```
 try{
        AudioInputStream stream;
        AudioFormat format;
        DataLine.Info info;
        Clip clip;

        stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("Spring.wav"));

        format = stream.getFormat();
        info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
        clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(stream);
                  //plays the song
        clip.start();

                  //keeps the song on repeat
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Comment: java has a large collection of containers doesnt any one of them fit your fancies!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not actually play anything audible because the thread closes immediately. In my example I added a thread.sleep command. The next issue: get rid of the clip.loop line because you don't want that.
   The idea in my version of this is to split the player up to its own class which will play from the main. That way, you can make an instance of the player play a tune one time, and then, switch it up any way you would like. I chose to play each wave file one after the other in the example, but you can play randomly or an whole array of wave files if you like:

The Class:

```
package scrapAudioClips;

import java.io.File;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;

public class AudioPlayer {

public void play(String filename) {
//The filename and time to play are passed into the method.
    try {
        AudioInputStream stream1;
        AudioFormat format = null;
        DataLine.Info info;
        Clip clip;


        stream1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filename));


        format = stream1.getFormat();

        info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
        clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(stream1);

//These next two lines will get the length of the wave file for you...
        long frames = stream1.getFrameLength();
        double durationInSeconds = (frames+0.0) / format.getFrameRate();

        // plays the song
        clip.start();

        // clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY); You don't need this anymore.

        Thread.sleep((long)(durationInSeconds * 1000)); // This allows you to actually hear the audio for the time in seconds..

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("File not recognized");
    }
}
```

}

Main:

```
package scrapAudioClips;

public class scrapAudio {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer();

    //you may play sequentially or in any random order you want with any loop     structure you like...
    player.play("Alesis.wav"); //You just pass the file name in... 
    player.play("wavefile1.wav");//Make your own playlist class as an array...
    player.play("wavefile2.wav");//loop it randomly or in sequence...

}
```

}

Comment: "Your code will not actually play anything audible because the thread closes immediately. " <- what thread? there is no thread in this code.

Comment: When I used it to play a file, it did not play until I inserted the thread.sleep() . But I was running it from within Eclipse, if there's a better way other than thread.sleep() I would do that.

Comment: Thanks dude, this code looks great. Only thing is the Thread.sleep() sleeps the thread my game is playing on.

Comment: If your original code worked on your system without the Thread.sleep() in it, then comment it out and try it, but on my system for some reason I needed it to hear the wave file. Please accept answer if this was of help.

Comment: Hmm, when I comment it out, all the files play at once. I'll try to figure it out.